# Unable to read appointment details EWS

Tags: java, exchangewebservices

This is my code:

```
CalendarView cView = new CalendarView(startDate, endDate, 100);
PropertySet PropSet = new PropertySet(AppointmentSchema.Subject, 
            AppointmentSchema.Start,
            AppointmentSchema.End, 
            AppointmentSchema.IsAllDayEvent, 
            AppointmentSchema.IsMeeting,
            AppointmentSchema.IsRecurring, 
            AppointmentSchema.IsCancelled,
            AppointmentSchema.IsDraft, 
            AppointmentSchema.Location,
            AppointmentSchema.Resources,
            AppointmentSchema.RequiredAttendees, 
            AppointmentSchema.OptionalAttendees,
            AppointmentSchema.LegacyFreeBusyStatus,
            AppointmentSchema.Organizer, 
            AppointmentSchema.Body,
            AppointmentSchema.Sensitivity,
            AppointmentSchema.AppointmentReplyTime,
            AppointmentSchema.AppointmentSequenceNumber,
            AppointmentSchema.AppointmentState,
            AppointmentSchema.AppointmentType,
            AppointmentSchema.ConferenceType,
            AppointmentSchema.DateTimeCreated,
            AppointmentSchema.Duration,
            AppointmentSchema.EndTimeZone,
            AppointmentSchema.HasAttachments,
            AppointmentSchema.ICalDateTimeStamp,
            AppointmentSchema.ICalRecurrenceId,
            AppointmentSchema.ICalUid,
            AppointmentSchema.Id,
            AppointmentSchema.Importance,
            AppointmentSchema.IsOnlineMeeting,
            AppointmentSchema.IsReminderSet,
            AppointmentSchema.IsResponseRequested,
            AppointmentSchema.IsUnmodified,
            AppointmentSchema.LastModifiedTime,
            AppointmentSchema.LegacyFreeBusyStatus,
            AppointmentSchema.MeetingRequestWasSent,
            AppointmentSchema.MyResponseType,
            AppointmentSchema.MeetingWorkspaceUrl,
            AppointmentSchema.NetShowUrl,
            AppointmentSchema.OriginalStart,
            AppointmentSchema.ParentFolderId,
            AppointmentSchema.Recurrence,
            AppointmentSchema.ReminderDueBy,
            AppointmentSchema.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart,
            AppointmentSchema.StartTimeZone,
            AppointmentSchema.WebClientEditFormQueryString,
            AppointmentSchema.WebClientReadFormQueryString);
cView.setPropertySet(PropSet);
FindItemsResults<Appointment> results = service.findAppointments(folder.getId(),cView);
```

while I am iterating `results`, it's throwing the following exception:

```
microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.exception.service.remote.ServiceRequestException:
    The request failed. The property null can't be used in FindItem request.
```

Answer (score 0):

yea got it. I have to just load the property Set inside for loop like

```
for (Item item : results) {
        item.load(PropSet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, `findAppointments()` is a `FindItem` request. For a `FindItem` request, only "summary properties" are legal(See [comments](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api/blob/master/src/main/java/microsoft/exchange/webservices/data/core/PropertySet.java#L505) in microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.PropertySet#validateForRequest),

> Validates this property set instance for request to ensure that: ... 2. If only summary properties are legal for this request (e.g. FindItem) then only summary properties were specified.

which means every property you set must have a flag of `PropertyDefinitionFlags.CanFind`, like [Start](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api/blob/master/src/main/java/microsoft/exchange/webservices/data/core/service/schema/AppointmentSchema.java#L317) or [End](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api/blob/master/src/main/java/microsoft/exchange/webservices/data/core/service/schema/AppointmentSchema.java#L328). Some properties like [OriginalStart](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api/blob/master/src/main/java/microsoft/exchange/webservices/data/core/service/schema/AppointmentSchema.java#L335) is illegal, therefore an error like this should have been raised

> The property OriginalStart can't be used in FindItem request.